# Is user@host at the end of each key in authorized_keys necessary?

Tags: ssh

I have a set of 8 small servers that chat with each other over ssh logging in automatically.

Now I would like to have the `.ssh` directory of all the servers be identical.

Now my question is whether the `user@host` part at the end of each key really is necessary?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's entirely optional. This part of the field is a comment, so it's just an information, usually about where the key originally came from.

It's [described here](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man5/authorized_keys.5.html#lbAH) (the best reference I could find):

> AuthorizedKeysFile specifies the files containing public keys for
> public key authentication; if none is specified, the default is
> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2 Each line of the
> file contains one key (empty lines and lines starting with a `#' are
> ignored as comments). Protocol 1 public keys consist of the following
> space-separated fields: options, bits, exponent, modulus, comment.
> Protocol 2 public key consist of: options, keytype, base64-encoded
> key, **comment**. The options field is optional; its presence is
> determined by whether the line starts with a number or not (the
> options field never starts with a number). The bits, exponent,
> modulus, and comment fields give the RSA key for protocol version 1;
> **the comment field is not used for anything (but may be convenient for
> the user to identify the key).**

Comment: That is exactly the answer I wanted. Now I can have identical  ~/.ssh at least initially on all machines. Thank you.